# angular 2 input decorator why it need?

Tags: angular

I study Angular 2.I was faced with the task to transfer the data to the component of parent component.in Official documentation is written to use the @ input.No but I do not understand why the developers of angular 2 made it need?.Why would not have made a transfer without @ INPUT.Why add @Input?In documentation in explain it is not clear for me

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318575/angular-2-typescript-input-output-or-input-output/41319049#41319049

Answer (score 3):

To define an input for a component, use the @Input decorator.

For example  component needs a user argument to render information about that user:

```
<user-profile [user]="currentUser"></user-profile>
```

So, you need to add an @Input binding to user:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-profile',
  template: '<div>{{user.name}}</div>'
})
export class UserProfile {
  @Input() user;
  constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bindings in components template like `[inputProp]="someValue"` are only allowed for `@Input() inputProp;` or native properties of HTML elements with matching names.

I'm only guessing but 2 explanations come to my mind

- more efficient code or code generation
  If properties need to be made explicit, this allows more efficient code
- better support for tools
  This allows tools to check for errors in your code, provide autocompletion when writing templates, and probably more