# How to update value of header component based content on component using route in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a header component , a footer component , Nav component and Content component on a Page.

```
 <sa-header></sa-header>
    <sa-navigation></sa-navigation>           
    <div id="main" role="main">
   // I have put Profile page here using routing and I have First name and last name on profile page
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>    
    <sa-footer></sa-footer>
```

Now in router-outlet, I have put a profile page using routing with first name and last name and based on first name and last name of profile page I want to display that name in Header component.

In Header page I have below code:

```
 <div> <span>{{user.displayName }}</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></div>
```

I try with below link but not useful in my case.

[Angular 2 - Update @input value of component on click on different component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170031/angular-2-update-input-value-of-component-on-click-on-different-component)

[Angular 2/TypeScript: @Input/@output or input/output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318575/angular-2-typescript-input-output-or-input-output)

I also try get and set those name in session but my header page load first so once I change in profile page it dose not effect header page.

How to change name in header page?

Comment: I think you have two options. 1. Pass the user object to the header component like `<sa-header [user]="user"></sa-header>`. 2. Use a service to get and set your global user information.

Comment: @Hinrich 3 , I try second option but when I set Display name from profile page then How it will automatically update Header page name? Can You also please give more information of option 1? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use service to communicate from inner component to outer component

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: This is the right approach. Thx! Additional you can take a look here: https://gist.github.com/rjmccluskey/46dfe9ed6abd4990b4f1a03263ace6de